# Appending literal text to a file

Tags: file, batch-file, text, echo

So here is my code

```
@echo off
:top
cls
echo Welcome to your custom terminal, Ayden
set /p enter=Enter:
if %enter% == start echo start > temp.txt
if %enter% == start goto top
if %enter% == live goto live
del executable.bat >nul
echo @echo off > executable.bat
notepad executable.bat
goto top
:live
cls
:overthere
set /p input=Ayden:
(
echo @echo off
) > executable.bat
echo echo %input% > temp2.txt >> executable.bat
pause
:overhere
if not exist temp2.txt goto overhere
type temp2.txt
del temp2.txt
goto overthere
```

But "executable.bat" ends up containing this

```
@echo off
echo dir
```

is there any way that I can make "echo dir" into "echo dir > temp2.txt"?
I have tried quotations, while that does work there is still one problem, that is when it is echoed to the file it still has the quotations around it.

Comment: If someone enters [Enter]/[return] your batch will fail as the left side of the comparison is empty. Add a constant to both sides to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the `>` that you want to echo, like this: `^>`.

Also, watch out putting a space before `>` and `>>` because that space gets echoed too.